# Word Scramble Not Scrambling Words

Tags: java, string, algorithm, sorting, chars

This program is supposed to shuffle the letters in the strings input, how ever it is just repeating the input. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, the issue seems to be in the scrambler function. Thank you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String str = in.next();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

//shuffle letters in word besides first and last 
public static String scrambler(String str, Random r) {

    //basic char array for input strings 
    char[] a = str.toCharArray();

    //scramble letters 
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        //shuffle letters in word besides first and last 
        int j = r.nextInt(a.length);

        char temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
    return new String(a);
}
```

Comment: The `scrambler` method works just fine, but your `main` method doesn't call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling Scrambler method, you should write

```
public static void main( String[] args){

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  Random r = new Random();
  while(in.hasNext()){
    String str = in.next();
    System.out.println(scrambler(str,r));
  }
```

Comment: thanks.. if I wanted to leave the first and last chars in place how would I go about that?

Comment: I assume start at ` i = 1` and end at `a.length -1`?

Comment: I suggest using    r.nextInt(a.length - 2) +1 so you leave back first and last characters. Please check correct answer.

Comment: I get a bounds error when I try this: `r.nextInt(a.length - 2)+1`

Comment: of course you have to check if the length of the word (size of the char array) is long enough. nextInt( X ) return a value between  0 and X (excluded) ; so if your word is almost 4 characters , we have 4-2, so X value is 2 and  nextInt return a value from 0 to 1. Add to it 1 and you have a value of 1 or 2. a[1] is the second character and a[2] is the third.

Comment: Would I do this by adding another for loop?

Comment: no simply check that your work is longer the 3 characters so add  if (a.length >3) j= r.nextInt(a.length -2 ) +1;

Comment: what is the "j" after `(a.length >3)` for?

Comment: did you mean `if (a.length > 3); j = r.nextInt(a.length-2)+1;`